# Simple webservice example tomEE not working

Tags: java, android, sockets, soap, proxy

I'm trying to deploy the simple WS example from tomEE:
http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-webservice/

As there is nothing special about it, I will post in detail what I did. Maybe someone sees what I'm doing wrong:

Machine: Win7, Eclipse, Server: tomEE+

-created new Dynamic Web Project with runtime target = the tomcat tomEE server

-created new package in /src, and added 3 classes there: `Calculator`, `CalculatorWS`, `CalculatorTest`.

-rightclick project > run as > run on server > choose tomEE.

Server starts up, launches `http://127.0.0.1:8080/testproject`

Which results in 404, as I have not set up any jsf page.
Anyhow, going to  `http://localhost:8080/testproject/Calculator?wsdl` or  `http://localhost:8080/testproject/webservices/Calculator?wsdl` as the example suggests, I too get 404 not found. Obvious the Webservices are not deployed?

What could be wrong with this basic and simple example?

Comment: When you deploy your service to tomact, you will see logs that service deployed with url etc., check server console.

Comment: hmm I don't see any wsdl urls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using eclipse indigo and tomee 1.5.2. I have a class x.y.z.MyWS. It's annotated with @WebService and @Stateless.

The apache tomee log, during startup, says

```
INFO: Webservice(wsdl=http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/webservices/MyWS, qname={http://z.y.x/}MyWSService) --> Ejb(id=MyWS)
```

So the WSDL is

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/webservices/MyWS?wsdl
```

Please check your logs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this example the other day, and ran into similar issues.  The solution is really to look into the Apache Logs folder for the catalina log for the date, and also for the stderr file for today's date.  They will tell you if the deployment worked or failed.

In my case, I was using JDEV, so I had removed the @Stateless annotation, and tried just dropping the .jar into the webapps folder.  That *did not* work.  However, putting it back in, and dropping the .jar worked fine.

As a web application (.war), the .class files were moved into WEB-INF\classes within the .war file and I dropped that into webapps.  I looked at the Catalina Log and it said where the endpoint was (for the wsdl).  I typed:
http://localhost:8080/SimpleWebService/Calculator?wsdl, and the WSDL file appeared.

After that, I ran some simple Soap Requests with soap ui.  It worked fine.  this was with version 1.7.1.