# How to change the 'webservices' path generated by @WebService on TomEE

Tags: java, web-services, apache-tomee

I'm learning the ropes of annotating my classes with @WebService I noticed that when I deploy to TomEE-plus (v1.6) I get an additional 'webservices' word in the url.

I want to either remove it or rename it if possible.

Given this code for an Eclipse project named WebAPI-DEV:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@Stateless
@WebService
public class WEBAPIImplementation {
    public List<Client> getClientsByTerm(String term) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I find on the catalina log the following:

```
Dec 10, 2013 3:49:05 PM org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsService deployApp
INFO: Webservice(wsdl=http://mylocalhost.com:8080/WebAPI-DEV/webservices/WEBAPIImplementation, qname={http://mylocalhost.com:8080/webapi}WEBAPIImplementationService) --> Ejb(id=WEBAPIImplementation)
```

The url `http://mylocalhost.com:8080/WebAPI-DEV/webservices/WEBAPIImplementation` has 'webservices' included.

I would rather have more control on defining the exact name of my webservice url.

Is that possible?

**UPDATE (2013-DEC-16):**
I followed the simple tutorial from

> http://blog.sortedset.com/step-by-step-web-services-with-tomcat-tomee-apache-cxf-eclipse/

Basically the parameters in the @Webservice annotation cause errors like this:

```
org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=TEST-WS)
```

and...

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[mylocalhost.com].StandardContext[/TEST-WS]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
```

and...

```
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0\webapps\TEST-WS.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[mylocalhost.com].StandardContext[/TEST-WS]]
```

Originally I had these parameters for @Webservice `(replace sortedset.com for localhost):`

```
@WebService(
        portName = "HelloTomEEPort",
        serviceName = "HelloTomEEService",
        targetNamespace = "http://localhost/wsdl",
        endpointInterface = "HelloTomEEWs")
```

Here are my two source files (I started a new project from scratch):

**TESTWS.java**

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public interface TESTWS {    
    public int sum(int add1, int add2); 
    public int multiply(int mul1, int mul2);
}
```

**TESTWSImpl.java**

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@Stateless
@WebService
public class TESTWSImpl implements TESTWS { 
    public int sum(int add1, int add2) {
        return add1 + add2;
    } 
    public int multiply(int mul1, int mul2) {
        return mul1 * mul2;
    }
}
```

This code allows TomEE to startup but when I request the url (as found in the catalina.log):

> http://mylocalhost.com:8080/TEST-WS/webservices/TESTWSImpl

I get this error:

```
Dec 16, 2013 5:21:57 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://mylocalhost.com/wsdl}TESTWSImplService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No such operation: TEST-WS (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /TEST-WS/webservices/TESTWSImplnull)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.URIMappingInterceptor.handleMessage(URIMappingInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:237)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfWsContainer.onMessage(CxfWsContainer.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsServlet.service(WsServlet.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What causes the "No such operation"?

Where can I find good documentation for the parameters of @Webservice?

**NOTE:** Replace mylocalhost.com with localhost

**UPDATE (2013-DEC-17):**
I was calling the webservice incorrectly, the proper url should be:

> http://mylocalhost.com:8080/TEST-WS/webservices/TESTWSImpl?wsdl

Referenced at

> [Simple webservice example tomEE not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854286/simple-webservice-example-tomee-not-working)

I guess I will learn to live with this generated url path ('webservices') until I understand more of how to configure it.

**UPDATE (2014-JAN-20):**
I completed one approach with `Enpoint.publish` and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This thread is quite old, but still I will like to share some links.
Its possible to remove 'webservices' from the webservice path deployed in [tomee](/questions/tagged/tomee). We need to specify a property as 

`tomee.jaxws.subcontext = /` 

or

`tomee.jaxws.subcontext =` 

in 

`conf/system.properties`

Here are the links for information

[Support Forum for TomEE+ - CXF Configuration](http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/TomEE-CXF-Configuration-td4631682.html)

[Apache Tomee site Change JAXWS URL](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/change-jaxws-url/README.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Thats the address of your WSDL located on your computer. You can find that folder and rename it accordingly. That's the max you can do.
Also you can replace localhost with your IP address.

Most of the time, at the time of WSDL generation you can configure "`WebAPI-DEV/webservices/WEBAPIImplementati`" this part of WSDL. 
For example if you try to make a mock webservice in SOAP UI, there you can configure all parts of the WSDL URL except localhost/IP address.

As of my knowledge.
 "Master yourself! Master the enemy!"

Comment: I tried to look for the wsdl file and found nothing. I googled some references indicating WEB-INF/schemas but that directory wasn't even created.

Answer (score 1):

The url /WebAPI-DEV/webservices/WEBAPIImplementation has 'webservices' included.

The above url is not your webservice url. Its the location on your server where, this wsdl is located.

Open this url in web browser, your wsdl will be opened.
Now search for  tag in wsdl, within this tag there would be  tag. This will be your webservice end point url. There you won't find this addidtional "webservices" word.

This "address location" will be invoked when sombody will call your webservice.

Yes, you can absolutly control defining yoyr webservice url.

Normally while generating  webservice, following format is followed,

"http://://"

something like above forma.It actually depends, where are you generating webservice, i mean on which tool.

FOr example: In SAP PI (integration tool), webservice url format is like this,

https://:/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&senderService=&receiverParty=&receiverService=&interface=&interfaceNamespace=

As per requirement you can control above address.

Regards,
ambuj
"Master yourself, Master the enemy"

Comment: http://<server>:<port>/<API name or message or transport protocol name>/<class name>"

Comment: No, it didn't work. I followed the example from http://blog.sortedset.com/step-by-step-web-services-with-tomcat-tomee-apache-cxf-eclipse/ and actually I had to remove all of the parameters from the @Webservice annotation so it could pick up default values, otherwise it TommEE would reject it.

Comment: Hi Salvador, I have gone through some JAX-WS implementation tutorial. Now i can say, you can configure your end point url completely. Look out for url publisher class where you are publishing endpoint url. For example  Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9899/ws/image", new ImageServerImpl()); Here you can set your url as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks user3090039, I got something working with Endpoint.publish

Comment: great work Salvador, Thanks for sharing your findings with us.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `user3090039`'s response I have implemented a partial solution that solved the urgency to implement a Webservice. I have implemented a Java program where from the main() method I deploy an Ednpoint. I have two classes WSServer and OrderSearch. WSServer is the main class which creates the Endpoint and passes the deploy/publish details to the OrderSearch class.

This `WSServer` class contains the main() method and launches and configures the Endpoint:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class WSServer {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Read application parameters into appSettings...
      AppParams appSettings = readAppParams(propFileName);

      //Create Endpoint, delegate configuration...
      Endpoint.publish(appSettings.getWSEndPoint(), new OrderSearch(appSettings));
      System.out.println("OrderSearch service is ready");
   }
}
```

The `AppParams` class looks like this (simplified):

```
public class AppParams {
   private String ws_end_point;
   // Other private parameters here...
   // Include appropiate getters and setters...
}
```

The method `getWSEndPoint()` returns a string similar to: `http://mylocalhost/prodOrders` this publishes the WSDL like this: `http://mylocalhost/prodOrders?wsdl`

And finally the OrderSearch class contains the public webmethods that will be published in the WSDL:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public class OrderSearch {
    public OrderSearch(AppParams settings) {
        // Use the settings object to initialize your business objects...
    }

    public List<ProductOrder> getOrdersByMonth(String orderMonth) {
       List<ProductOrder> orderList = null;

       orderList = dataAdapter.getOrdersByMonth(String orderMonth);

       return orderList;
    }
}
```

The Class `ProductOrder` is just a simle POJO with the attributes that your webservice consumers will need (i.e. order date, order number, product id, etc.) This POJO is used to build the XML structure that will be send back to the consumer/user.

Notice that the Endpoint needs a String and an Implementor (OrderSearch) which will be in charge of processing each request.

There are many more options on how to use the Endpoint as (briefly) described by Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html

There are still many questions on how to customize the Endpoint URL but this is what I got working. Hopefully better documentation will be available in the future.

My next task is to move this to be run by TOMEE+ any tips?