# Exposing an EJB project as SOAP WebService in another project

Tags: java, web-services, soap, ejb

I have 2 different JAVA projects (in Eclipse), one of them is all the required JPA implementation for accessing to the DB, where the classes that encapsulate all the work are beans tagged as @Stateless and @LocalBean.
The second project wants to be a SOAP Web Service implementation offering those methods, that classes just have to call the beans

Speaking about code, on that project must be a SOAP implementation I have something like:

```
package implementacion;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

    @Stateless
    @WebService(targetNamespace = "http://implementacion/", portName = "TestPort", serviceName = "TestService")
    public class Test {
        @EJB
        private LanguageBO lbo;

        public Test(){

        }

        public String sayHello() {
            return "Hello world";
        }

        public String sayBye() {
            return "Bye world";
        }

        public WSCollectionResult getAllLanguages() {
            return lbo.getAllLanguages();
        }
    }
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SOAPBorrar</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

My cxf-beans.xml (WS implementation is inside the package "implementation", and it is called Test):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <jaxws:endpoint id="test" implementor="implementation.Test"
        wsdlLocation="wsdl/test.wsdl" address="/test">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

I have tried to implement the WebService as @Stateless and as nothing, but I have still some exceptions during the deployment:

```
Grave: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'test': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91 to org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.wsdl.extensions.SoapBinding
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91 to org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.wsdl.extensions.SoapBinding
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:371)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91 to org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.wsdl.extensions.SoapBinding
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3094)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SOAPBindingUtil.getProxy(SOAPBindingUtil.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SOAPBindingUtil.getSoapBinding(SOAPBindingUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SOAPBindingUtil.getSoapBinding(SOAPBindingUtil.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.createBindingInfo(SoapBindingFactory.java:676)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildBinding(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:486)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:354)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:428)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:548)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    ... 30 more

mar 21, 2014 2:21:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'test': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91 to org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.wsdl.extensions.SoapBinding
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91 to org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.wsdl.extensions.SoapBinding
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:371)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91 to org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.wsdl.extensions.SoapBinding
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3094)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SOAPBindingUtil.getProxy(SOAPBindingUtil.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SOAPBindingUtil.getSoapBinding(SOAPBindingUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SOAPBindingUtil.getSoapBinding(SOAPBindingUtil.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.createBindingInfo(SoapBindingFactory.java:676)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildBinding(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:486)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:354)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:428)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:548)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    ... 30 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Apache TomEE as EJB server and CXF for implementing those WS. Also, if I don't use that EJB (if I comment @EJB private LanguageBO and the method using it) the WS works correctly, what am I missing?

Thank you in advance :)

PD: I've created the WS using Eclipse's wizard for that

PD2: I've realized if I use @Stateless annotation in the WS implementation it doesn't work

**EDITED**

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eu.superhub.wp4.policyframework-web-server</groupId>
    <artifactId>policyframework-web-server</artifactId>
    <name>SUPERHUB policyframework-web-server SIP</name>
    <description>Incorporates clients of other WP4 modules and provides a web-service interface</description>
    <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>
            <!-- With this dependency, the warning message – “Selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored” will be fixed-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!-- With this property, the character encoding warnings will be fixed-->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Own bundles dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.superhub.wp4.models</groupId>
            <artifactId>policymodel</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>           
        </dependency>       
        <!-- REST Services dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.7.4</version> -->
            <version>2.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.7.4</version> -->
            <version>2.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.7.4</version> -->
            <version>2.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.6.0</version> -->
            <version>2.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Without this dependency the REST Service can't serialize the List data types -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logger dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>         
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>  
        <!-- PostgreSQL dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>   
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId> 
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependency>             
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

Comment: Do you use last tomee? Do you deliver cxf in your webapp which is needed to use spring.

Comment: I'm using apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0, and I've been able to use REST and SOAP services, the problem is combining them with EJB :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally fixed it... sometimes asking the most simple things works.
That user had the same problem as me:

[Simple webservice example tomEE not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854286/simple-webservice-example-tomee-not-working)

Basically the deployment wasn't wrong at all, the "problem" is Eclipse wasn't showing the correct URL for the WSDL, and I was fully trusting on that :P... on the log, between lots of errors have nothing to see with that, was the correct URL for the WSDL.

Thank you all for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue is cxf packages spring related classes so you need to provide spring AND cxf in the webapp or just dont use spring if possible

Comment: I attached my pom.xml... I added some Spring dependencies for CXF, maybe I am missing some